# Generate odoo 9 demo data

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, odoo-10

How can I add inputs (code and name) in the below example for module hr_payroll?

For example: input name is "Stimulation", code = "STM"

```xml
<record id="hr_rule_taxable" model="hr.salary.rule">
    <field name="name">Gross</field>
    <field name="sequence" eval="100"/>
    <field name="code">GROSS</field>
    <field name="category_id" ref="hr_payroll.GROSS"/>
    <field name="condition_select">none</field>
    <field name="amount_select">code</field>
    <field name="amount_python_compute">result = categories.BASIC + categories.ALW</field>
</record>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to override parts of this data in your module's XML?

If so, it can be done by using `<module_name>.<view_id>` to override certain fields from the same record, such as:

```
<record id="hr_payroll.hr_rule_taxable" model="hr.salary.rule">
    <field name="name">Stimulation</field>
    <field name="code">STM</field>
</record>
```

**Note: This does not work if the original record is in a `<data noupdate="1">` block.**

Comment: I want add STM in above example!

Comment: @Pointer Can you explain further? I'm not sure what you want that's not included in my answer so far.